# Open file from List Box C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

When I try to run this I get the same error every time telling me that the file has not been found, even though it clearly is in that folder. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thank You.

```
public TaskViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\To-Do-List");

        FileInfo[] Files = dInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            Path.GetDirectoryName(file.Name);
        }

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Process.Start(file);
    }
```

Comment: that's only listing the file name, you need to add the directory back before trying to run the file.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: also you have a literal string with `@` so you only need one slash

Answer (score 3):

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string fullFileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\To-Do-List", file);
    Process.Start(fullFileName);
}
```

Comment: No no, you had it right the first time. `String` doesn't have a `FullPath` property - that's on `FileInfo`.

Comment: ah yeah, you're right. i missed the `ToString()` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You are putting `file.Name` in the list-box, but that doesn't include the full path.

It looks like you're trying to do something about that with your `Path.GetDirectoryName(file.Name);`, however, that function returns a string and you are just throwing it away.

`Process.Start` needs the full path, or it will look in the current directory (probably your `bin` folder).

So, the easy fix would be to use `file.FullPath` instead of `file.Path`.

That will cause the full path to appear in the list box, however. If you don't want that, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29638914/369) by DLeh works if all the files are in the same folder.